# Aliasing array xml elements with RABL

Tags: rabl

I am trying to create xml output to match a legacy system's output and I'm not sure how to get my xml to match.  I basically need to rename the array elements node name to something different than the default.

Given I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Result
    attr_accessor :channel

    def initialize
      @channel = Array.new
    end
end
```

And a RABL template:

```
object @result
attributes :channel
```

I would like the xml to look like this:

```
<result>
  <channel>
    <value>running</value>
    <value>cycling</value>
  </channel>
</result>
```

Instead of this which comes out by default:

```
<result>
  <channel>
    <channel>running</channel>
    <channel>cycling</channel>
  </channel>
</result>
```

I am new to RABL and I couldn't find anything in the docs/interwebs on how to generate something like this.  Thanks in advance!